# CSS animation of position property not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So I got this snippet of code from my textbook and tried it out in my browser and the position transition for the top property is an instant jump instead of a slow transition down 50 pixels. I did some googling online and it seems like transitioning the position property is possible but for some reason it isn't working in my code.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PXBP/2/) version.

Here is the CSS related markup:

```
body {
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 6em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a {
   display: block;
  width: 6em;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  border: 2px solid rgb(175,175,175);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-shadow: #666 .1em .1em .1em;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 25s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 25s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 25s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 25s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 25s, box-shadow 0.2s;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  background-color: #fdca00;
  border-color: #fda700;
}
a:active {
  top: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Here is the HTML related markup:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Men</a></li>
<li><a href="">Women</a></li>
<li><a href="">Kids</a></li>
<li><a href="">SALE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure you want the top animation to take 25 seconds?  Think it should be `.25s`?

Comment: Right, I put it to 25 seconds as an extreme test to make sure it wasn't an issue with my eyes :P

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7PXBP/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7PXBP/3/)** the correct fiddle 
I just added `top:0px` in the tag `a`

```
a {
   display: block;
  width: 6em;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  border: 2px solid rgb(175,175,175);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-shadow: #666 .1em .1em .1em;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: relative;
   top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 1s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 1s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 1s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 1s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s, top 1s, box-shadow 0.2s;
}
```

Hope is what are you looking for :)

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect, could you please explain why this addition fixed the problem?